# Does $\Delta U$ depend on which type of gas is considered?

Tags: thermodynamics

$\Delta U$ is a state function, hence it only depends on the 'end-points'. Let's imagine that there's a gas confined in an isolated container. For an Ideal Gas, a reversible isothermal expansion implies that $\Delta T = 0 \Rightarrow \Delta U = 0$. Would $\Delta U$ still be $0$ for the same process, for a Real Gas? If so, then why?

Comment: $U$ and $\Delta U$ depend on temperature.  What does "isothermal" mean?

Comment: @DavidWhite As far as I know, isothermal means 'at constant temperature'

Comment: That was a rhetorical question intended to lead you to the answer.

Comment: To my knowledge, U is a function of V and T, for a Real Gas. So, eventhough T is constant, V can vary throughout the expansion. Suposedly, if the Real Gas expands, $\Delta V \neq 0$, then $\Delta U \neq 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, calculating $\Delta U$ requires a knowledge of what kind of gas you're talking about.

> Would $\Delta U$ still be 0 for the same process, for a Real Gas? If so, then why?

No, not in general.  An ideal gas is special because, assuming constant $N$ (or equivalently $n$, the number of moles of gas present), the internal energy is just a constant multiple of the temperature $T$.  This implies that if $\Delta T=0$, then $\Delta U=0$.

Not all gases have this property.  In particular, consider the [van der Waals gas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_der_Waals_equation), which has the equation of state

$$\left(P + a \frac{n^2}{V^2}\right)\left(V-nb\right) = nRT$$

Roughly speaking, the van der Waals gas is a modification of the ideal gas to account for finite molecular size as well as long-range attractive forces.  It requires a bit of work (and several additional inputs - see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_der_Waals_equation#Other_thermodynamic_parameters)) to show, but the internal energy of a monatomic van der Waals gas is

$$U = \frac{3}{2}nRT - a\frac{n^2}{V}$$

Unlike the case of the ideal gas, the van der Waals internal energy is volume dependent, and can therefore be changed even during isothermal processes.

Comment: Comment #1: I was considering to edit the answer because there is an inconsistent usage of *n* and *N*, without explaining the difference. However, due to the presence of other quantities like  U and V and the presence of the symbol R, I gave up. I think the author could decide better the choice of the symbols. The presente formulae wold be correct if n and N both represent the number of atoms and R is fro the Boltzmann constant. In wikipedia, the notation is for the molar quantities, but in that case V and U should be the molar volume and energy.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  $n$ refers to the number of moles of the substance, while $N$ refers to the number of particles.  The choice of whether to use $(n,R)$ or $(N,k_B)$ is purely a conventional one, and the formulae are correct whichever you decide to use.

Comment: Comment #2: from the van der Waals equation of state (the relation between P,V,T and n) is simply impossible to obtain the above form of the energy as function of n,T and V. That formula is obtained from an approximation of the free energy from which both, the equation of state and the thermal behavior of energy are derived. That things go this way should be evident, for example, by considering that otherwise the same equation of state should provide the 3/2 factor of a monoatomic gas and the 5/2 of a diatomic gas.

Comment: I also never made the claim that the equation of state was sufficient to derive the exact form of the internal energy.  I only wrote down the equation of state to illustrate the difference from the ideal gas.  In any case, please feel free to write your own answer correcting any of my errors.

Comment: I agree on the conventional choice of symbols. But since there are quite common conventions it is useful to state explicitly which one one is using. If you stick on the usual choice and n is the number of moles, U and V should be the internal molar energy and the molar volume. But, in the second paragraph of your answer you mention energy instead of molar energy.

Comment: It is an extremely common convention to use the number of moles but not the molar energy or molar volume.

Comment: Your answer is good. I was just driving your attention on two minor inaccuracies, to improve it.

Comment: I appreciate that.  I'll adjust my answer to make a note that you need more input to derive the exact equation for the internal energy.